# Mist Continually Having Sync Troubles

Tags: go-ethereum, bug

Since the Geth issue it's been near impossible to keep up with the blockchain syncing, because it will often get stuck on one block forever.

I've been trying to copy these instructions from a similar question that got lots of upvotes:

If you are on a Mac, you would do this...

- Right click on the ethereum-wallet.app and select 'show package contents'
- Open 'contents', then 'frameworks', then 'node', then 'geth' and voila.
- Then you should right click on geth and select 'show info'.
- Copy the location marked 'Where:'.
- Open Terminal and type 'cd `
- Then type: ./geth --fast

However these instructions make no sense to me. The whole instruction says to copy a location and then proceeds to do nothing with that information.

What am I doing wrong? I tried the commands on the last two points in succession and nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

The instruction "Open Terminal and type 'cd `" seems to be incomplete as it does not tell you to paste the copied location. The next command (./geth --fast) will only work if you're in the folder where ./geth is present (./ means current folder). Your question hints at this when you say "...the instruction says to copy...and then do nothing with that info..."  So, do something with the copied info by pasting it to the 'cd' command.

Comment: I'm still confused, sorry. The Location after I follow the first several steps is: /Applications/Ethereum Wallet.app/Contents/nodes/geth/mac-x64. I don't know what "pasting it to the 'cd' command" entails. Do I copy this address and put 'cd' before it or after it in a terminal command? Do I press enter and then do the stated ./geth --fast command or do I put this in the same command?

Comment: When you copy something it goes into the paste buffer (on Mac it's Control+C). To paste it (on a Mac) it's Control+V.  Don't know how it works on your operating system. So copy and then paste after 'cd ' (don't forget the space so as to separate the command (cd) from the destination.

Comment: You could also skip the `cd` step and just run `/Applications/Ethereum\ Wallet.app/Contents/nodes/geth/mac-x64/geth --fast` from your terminal.